# PySide2 pass mouse events to system

Tags: python, pyside2, qmouseevent

I'm using a `QDialog` with transparency enabled to select a region of the screen for a screen capture tool. When the user clicks inside the transparent widget I want to ignore the mouse event so that the system handles it. Is this possible?

I'm trying to achieve this on Linux.

Some things I have tried with no success:

- `QtWidgets.QWidget.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowTransparentForInput)`
- `QtWidgets.QWidget.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)`
- `QtWidgets.QWidget.setMask(QtGui.QRegion(self.geometry()))`
- Subclassing `mousePressEvent` and ignoring the event

Comment: try with: `w.setWindowFlags(w.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowTransparentForInput| QtCore.Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint)`

Comment: That helped me to solve it. If you make this into an answer I'll kindly accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the flag `X11BypassWindowManagerHint` so that you omit the window manager next to `WindowTransparentForInput` so that the system knows that it only has to show the window but does not notify you about the inputs.

```
w.setWindowFlags(w.windowFlags() | 
    QtCore.Qt.WindowTransparentForInput | 
    QtCore.Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint)
```